# Using the Canvas for web animation results in nothing happening?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm learning javascript, so a coworker is having me do basic animation in the browser.  I just finished my code, using the canvas element to display images to the screen, but nothing happens when I run the code.  My debug statements don't get printed to the console, nor do any errors.  Can anyone see a problem with my code?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="console" width="600" height="600"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function() {
                console.log("at top of script");
                var ballImage = new Image();
                ballImage.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg";

                var time_stamp;
                var balls[];
                var BALL_COUNT = 2;

                function requestAnimFrame (cb) {
                    function fallback (cb){
                        window.setTimeout(cb, 10);
                    }                     
                    var func = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        fallback;
                   func (cb);      
                }               


                function update() {
                    var ts = Date.now();
                    var time_elapsed = ts - (time_stamp || ts);
                    time_stamp = ts;
                    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

                    // update ball positions and detect wall collisions
                    balls.forEach(function (ball){
                        canvas.clearRect( ball.xLocation, ball.yLocation, ball.scaleWidth, ball.scaleHeight );
                        ball.update(time_elapsed);
                        canvas.drawImage( ball.image, ball.xLocation, ball.yLocation, ball.scaleWidth, ball.scaleHeight );
                    });
                }

                function programRun() {
                    update();
                    requestAnimationFrame(programRun);
                }


                /*
                    CLASS: ball
                 */
                 function Ball() {
                    // all the code and functions for the ball class....
                 }              


                ballImage.onload = function() {
                    // fill up the array containing the ball objects
                    for (var i = 0; i < BALL_COUNT; ++i){
                        balls.push (new Ball ("ball" + i));
                    }
                    // start running the program
                    programRun();
                };
                console.log("got to end of script");

            }) ();
        <script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm almost certain it's some basic thing I messed up, because I didn't get any errors back from running the code.  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Could you add the code for the Ball class?

Answer (score 0):

This line caused it..

```
var balls[];
```

correct it by replacing it with:

```
var balls = [];
```

you should see the logs then.

Update:

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/nAT99/) with the code above and revised some fragments of your code to conform to a version that may suit your needs in writing your own version of the ball animation.

The following are the problems that I saw in your code:

1. Of course the array declaration mentioned above `var balls[];` to `var balls = [];`
2. Don't forget to declare variables with the `var` keyword. I changed

   time_stamp = ts;
   canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

to

```
var time_stamp = ts;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

3. Your html code suggests that the ID of the canvas is `id="console"` but your javascript tries to get an element with `id="canvas"`.

Changed

`<canvas id="console" width="600" height="600"></canvas>`

to

`<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>`

1. Inside your ball.each() iteration uses the canvas element to invoke methods that are supposed to be within the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).
   Add something after your `var canvas` declaration.

   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

use the `ctx` variable to manipulate the canvas itself. This should be your `function update()` definition.

```
function update() {
    var ts = Date.now();
    var time_elapsed = ts - (time_stamp || ts);
    var time_stamp = ts;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // update ball positions and detect wall collisions
    balls.forEach(function (ball){
        ctx.clearRect( ball.xLocation, ball.yLocation, ball.scaleWidth, ball.scaleHeight );
        ball.update();
        ctx.drawImage( ballImage, ball.xLocation, ball.yLocation, ball.scaleWidth, ball.scaleHeight );
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

Always use `var` when declaring variables. If you want to use them as a variable that can be accessed from different scopes(inner scopes) then you can do it by declaring them a scope higher.

Something like this:

```
function BallAnimation() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function updateBall() {
    ctx.fillRect(.....);
    ...
  }

  function Ball() {
    this.canvas = canvas;
  }

}
```

In such a manner you can still obtain the reference of the variables that you want to share from other scopes. Read this [article](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2076-why-you-should-use-the-var-keyword-in-javascript/) to know more why `var`s are important.

Comment: I made that change and the program still outputs nothing.  I'll keep looking for more errors though.

Comment: Please check my update, I have created a fiddle for the ball animation.

Comment: Looking at what you said about not having used 'var' before declaring variables, I'm finding myself a bit confused. I know we can cache values in a function, so that between calls a variable inside the function still has it's value (behaving like a static variable?).  If I don't use the 'var' keyword before assigning a value to a variable, what happens?  Also, how do I make a variable retain it's value between calls to a function?